# Ubuntu Server VMware Keyboard Login Problem

Tags: server, keyboard, login, password

My name is Jeff and I am new to using the services of Linux OS and this concerns using the Ubuntu Server Image to create an Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Virtual Server in VMware Workshop Application.

My problem is that the keyboard does not work when entering the password, to login.
The keyboard does allow me to enter the username.

So I cannot login because the keyboard will not access entering the password at password level.

I did enter a picture showing that the Ubuntu Server has been installed which, but I received a quickviewed message saying I cannot post pictures.

[Showing Ubuntu Server inside VMware Application Login Attempt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IPhI.png)

I do not know if I can be more technical than this, but I hope that maybe someone might be able to let me know if I have missed something.

Comment: The password isn't echoed, i.e., you won't see any dots, asterisks or anything similar if that's what you're expecting. Simply type it and press ENTER.

Comment: Off-topic: http://www.changanuk.com/Careers ;)

Comment: Dear ChanganAuto, Thank you for your instruction. It seems that I was not patient to wait for my data to be submitted. I followed a video once realised I was logged in and followed many commands. The last is "netstat -ntul", but though I have reached this point, no server has loaded to be displayed. Thank you again.